# Java - How to call an oracle procedure with custom types?

Tags: java, oracle, struct, plsql, user-defined-types

I have a plsql procedure

```
PROCEDURE merge_time_bounds(s1_bd_t IN bd_tb_struct, s2_bd_t IN bd_tb_struct, r_bd_t OUT bd_tb_struct);
```

And I try to call it inside of my Java Code. I did it already with other procedures where all parameters was of type VARCHAR, but here all params are "bd_tb_struct"

```
create or replace TYPE bd_tb_struct FORCE
AS
OBJECT
(
start_ts   TIMESTAMP (3) ,
end_ts     TIMESTAMP (3) ,
time_type  NUMBER (19) ,
duration   NUMBER (12) ) FINAL ;
```

I also have a Java Class with this Comment. "Class of the corresponding type in the database. (bd_tb_struct )"

```
BoundsSqlType.java
```

Can some one explain me how I can call my procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BD_TB_STRUCT AS OBJECT(
  start_ts TIMESTAMP(3),
  end_ts   TIMESTAMP(3),
  time_type NUMBER(19),
  duration NUMBER(12)
) FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE merge_time_bounds(
  s1_bd_t IN  bd_tb_struct,
  s2_bd_t IN  bd_tb_struct,
  r_bd_t  OUT bd_tb_struct
)
IS
  p_start TIMESTAMP(3) := LEAST(    s1_bd_t.start_ts,  s2_bd_t.start_ts );
  p_end   TIMESTAMP(3) := GREATEST( s1_bd_t.end_ts,    s2_bd_t.end_ts );
BEGIN
  r_bd_t := new BD_TB_STRUCT( 
                  p_start,
                  p_end,
                  COALESCE( s1_bd_t.time_type, s2_bd_t.time_type ),
                  ( CAST( p_end AS DATE ) - CAST( p_start AS DATE ) ) * 24 * 60 * 60
                );
END;
/
```

**Java SQLData Class**:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.sql.SQLData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLInput;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class BoundsSQL implements SQLData
{
  public static final String SQL_TYPE = "BD_TB_STRUCT";
  public java.sql.Timestamp start;
  public java.sql.Timestamp end;
  public BigInteger type;
  public BigInteger duration;

  public BoundsSQL()
  {
  }

  public BoundsSQL(
      final int year,
      final int month,
      final int dayOfMonth,
      final int hour,
      final int minute,
      final int seconds,
      final long duration,
      final long type )
  {
    final long epochSeconds = LocalDateTime.of(
        year,
        month,
        dayOfMonth,
        hour,
        minute,
        seconds
      ).toEpochSecond( ZoneOffset.UTC );
    this.start    = new Timestamp( epochSeconds * 1000 );
    this.end      = new Timestamp( (epochSeconds + duration) * 1000 );
    this.duration = BigInteger.valueOf( duration );
    this.type = BigInteger.valueOf( type );
  }

  @Override
  public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException
  {
    return SQL_TYPE;
  }

  @Override
  public void readSQL( SQLInput stream,
      String typeName ) throws SQLException
  {
    start    = stream.readTimestamp();
    end      = stream.readTimestamp();
    type     = stream.readBigDecimal().toBigInteger();
    duration = stream.readBigDecimal().toBigInteger();
  }

  @Override
  public void writeSQL( SQLOutput stream ) throws SQLException
  {
    stream.writeTimestamp( start );
    stream.writeTimestamp( end );
    stream.writeBigDecimal( new BigDecimal( type ) );
    stream.writeBigDecimal( new BigDecimal( duration ) );
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format(
        "Start:    %s\nEnd:      %s\nDuration: %s\nType:     %s",
        start,
        end,
        duration,
        type
    );
  }
}
```

**Call Stored Procedure from Java**:

Call the stored procedure using `OracleCallableStatement#setObject( int, Object )` to pass parameters and put the class into a type map and use `OracleCallableStatement#registerOutParameter( int, int, string )` and `OracleCallableStatement#getObject( int )` to retrieve the parameters.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Map;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;

public class PassStructToProcedure
{

  public static void main( final String[] args ){
    OracleConnection con = null;
    try{
      Class.forName( "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" );

      con = (OracleConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(
          "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl",
          "USERNAME",
          "PASSWORD"
      );

      BoundsSQL bound1 = new BoundsSQL( 2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 10, 1 );
      BoundsSQL bound2 = new BoundsSQL( 2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 5, 10, 2 );

      OracleCallableStatement st = (OracleCallableStatement) con.prepareCall(
          "{ call MERGE_TIME_BOUNDS( ?, ?, ? ) }"
      );

      st.setObject( 1, bound1 );
      st.setObject( 2, bound2 );
      st.registerOutParameter( 3, OracleTypes.STRUCT, BoundsSQL.SQL_TYPE );
      st.execute();

      Map<String,Class<?>> typeMap = con.getTypeMap();
      typeMap.put( BoundsSQL.SQL_TYPE, BoundsSQL.class );

      BoundsSQL out = (BoundsSQL) st.getObject( 3 );

      System.out.println( out.toString() );

      st.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
      System.out.println( ex.getMessage() );
      ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try{
        if ( con != null )
          con.close();
      }
      catch( SQLException e )
      {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Start:    2019-01-01 00:00:00.0
End:      2019-01-01 00:00:15.0
Duration: 15
Type:     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `oracle.jdbc.OracleStruct` to map your custom type. Check Oracle's docs at https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraoot.htm#JJDBC28431

```
PreparedStatement ps= conn.prepareStatement("text_of_prepared_statement");
Struct mySTRUCT = conn.createStruct (...);
((OraclePreparedStatement)ps).setOracleObject(1, mySTRUCT);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a third party library, [jOOQ generates code for all of your PL/SQL packages, UDTs, procedures, functions](https://blog.jooq.org/the-best-way-to-call-stored-procedures-from-java-with-jooq/), etc. to spare you the hassle of doing the binding manually.

So, in your case, you could call your procedure like this, using the generated stubs:

```java
BdTbStructRecord result = Routines.mergeTimeBounds(
    configuration, // This contains your JDBC connection and other things
    new BdTbStructRecord(start1, end1, time1, duration1),
    new BdTbStructRecord(start2, end2, time2, duration2)
);
```

This does something similar to what the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54347047/521799) does with JDBC directly, but:

- You don't have to work with strings, everything type checks (and IDE auto completes)
- You don't have to remember data types and parameter order
- When you change the procedure in your database, and regenerate the code, then your client code stops compiling, so you'll notice the problem early on

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.