# How to map Java class to Oracle custom type to use as IN parameter in stored procedure?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, oracle11g

I'm trying to use a custom object in oracledb as IN parameter for a procedure, but I'm having issues sending it from my java application

I tried mapping the DTO class directly in 
`query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, CustomClass.class, ParameterMode.IN);`

Also I didn't find this particular question in stackoverflow

Java code:

```
    private String executeSP(CustomClass dto) {
    StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("PACKAGE.SOMEPROCEDURE");
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, CustomClass.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

    // Pass the parameter values
    query.setParameter(1, dto);

    // Execute query
    query.execute();

    // Get output parameters
    String response = (String) query.getOutputParameterValue(2);

    System.out.println(response);
    return response;
}
```

PL SQL Procedure:

```
PROCEDURE SOMEPROCEDURE (
  P_DTO                  IN     DTOTYPE (previously created)
  P_RESULT                  OUT     VARCHAR2);
```

Expected result: Hibernate maps the dto to the oracle custom object
Actual result: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - How to call an oracle procedure with custom types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54344166/java-how-to-call-an-oracle-procedure-with-custom-types)

Comment: I didn't have time to test this, took the short route and desisted on using an object in PL, should we close this question?